Which aluminum alloy is used in cheap commercial load cells?
I am planning to simulate a load cell in CAD and was wondering which aluminum alloy are cheap commercial load cells made of? I noticed there is no huge difference between the common aluminum alloys in terms of Young's modulus and poisson's ratio so I assume something like the 1060 and 6061 should not be much different right?
Thanks in advance.

I'm not sure if either of them would be used for a precision measuring device, but at a minimum you'd get more linear range out of the 6061 due to higher yield strength

If the Young's modulus is similar across the board, why do you need to know the alloy?  Are you concerned about yield strength?

I don't think I've ever seen a load cell that was not made out of steel, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

@PeteW thank you for the reply. Fair enough. the output I get is linear for load measurements so I assume thats a good way to go. Otherwise, what would you suggest? I gave both alloys as examples only.. Thanks in advance.

@TimWescott Thanks for the reply. I am using a CAD software for the simulation and I need to specify a material for the model. This will help me see correct strains and stresses compared to the physical load cell. I hope I got your question right.. Thanks in advance.

@RC_23 they do exist and are actually pretty common. Specially for lighter loads I guess... Thanks for the reply.

@DailyReader - The direct measurement is typically an electrical parameter which is related to local strain. So for measurement, it's important that the relationship between strain and the load on the whole cell is stable vs repeated cycling and vs temperature, has minimum hysteresis, ideally linear, ideally insensitive to temperature, and insensitive to transverse loads. Then there are sundry manufacturing considerations - aluminum alloys tend to be optimized for machining or sheet metal forming or welding etc. 6061 is a compromise, but not optimal for anything. 10xx is for electrical use

Another nice-to-have is ability of the load cell to withstand overload and shocks, without plastic deformation which would take it out of calibration. Corrosion resistance also good to have. I'd probably prioritize stress-strain hysteresis, yield strength, fatigue strength (really cycle limit per max specified use)

If you really want to get a model to match, you could make your own load cell from a material and send a piece of the same block to be tested for material properties. The big vendors like vishay have pretty good docs... Other than that, look up the Young's modulus for all the Al you think it could be.  You can get a pretty good read on your cell's by loading it via turning of a fine screw.

@PeteW thanks for the reply Pete. To be honest I checked the material properties on the CAD software and they seemed not much different for my application. So I guess I will stick with 6061 for now. I will also get in contact with a manufacturer in china maybe and ask them what do they make their load cells from inshAllah. Thanks again!

@Abel Thank you for your reply. Please check my reply to Pete...Thanks a lot!
